# Maximum Posterior: $ p(\bf{w}\mid\bf{x},\bf{t},\alpha,\beta) \propto p(\bf{t}\mid\bf{x},\bf{w},\beta)p(\bf{w}\mid\alpha) $ for Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bayesian

At the moment I take a look at the book **Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning** from **Christopher Bishop** and as I try to understand the basics of the probability theory I get stuck trying to understand the *maximum posterior* technique.

The equation says:

$$
p(\bf{w}\mid\bf{x},\bf{t},\alpha,\beta) \propto p(\bf{t}\mid\bf{x},\bf{w},\beta)p(\bf{w}\mid\alpha)
$$

Given is:

$$
\ln p(\bf{t}\mid\bf{x},\bf{w},\beta) = -\frac{\beta}{2} \sum_{n=1}^N (y(x_n,\bf{w}) - t_n)^2 + \frac{N}{2} \ln \beta - \frac{N}{2}\ln(2\pi)
$$

Which I was able to understand so far. But then as the chapter proceeds and it comes to  $ p(\bf{w}\mid\alpha) $, it just is **considered** that

$$ p(\bf{w}\mid\alpha) = \mathcal{N}(\bf{w}\mid\bf{0},\alpha^{-1}\bf{I}) = \left(\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{M+1}{2}} \exp\left\{-\frac{\alpha}{2}\bf{w}^T\bf{w}\right\} $$

but sadly it is not explained why this is the case. I tried to understand this myself but did not succeed since I am not such an enviably mathematician.

Could someone explain to me why the probability $ p(\bf{w}\mid\alpha) $ does look like this?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like it's just the prior, and that it is the joint distribution of $M+1$ $N(0, \alpha^{-1})$ independent variables. What are the different things ($\mathbf{w}$ in particular)?

Comment: $ w $ is a weight vector such that $ y(\bf{x},\bf{w})=w_10+w_1\Phi_1(x_1)+w_2\Phi_2(x_2)+...+w_N\Phi_N(x_N) $ is a model with base functions $ \Phi_i(x_i) $. $ \bf{t} $ is a target vector such that $ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(t_i - y(x_i, w))^2 $ is the mean squared error of the model respectively to our target (function). Later on it is shown that $ \nabla \ln p(\bf{t}\mid\bf{x},\bf{w},\beta) = (\lambda\bf{I} + \bf{\Phi}^T*\bf{\Phi})^{-1} \bf{\Phi} \bf{t} $.

Comment: **Correction**: ..that $ \nabla \ln p(\bf{t}\mid\bf{x},\bf{w},\beta) = (\lambda\bf{I} + \bf{\Phi}^T\bf{\Phi})^{-1} \bf{\Phi}^T \bf{t} $. For $ \lambda = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} $

Comment: I'm struggling now with the same thing as you are :)